# How do I refer to a specific branch of a private git repo in Terragrunt?

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

I want to refer to a `feature/IaC` (any specific branch other than the main) branch of a multibranch **private** git repo as a **source parameter of Terragrunt's configuration file**.

Here is a piece of code from my `terragrunt.hcl` file

```
terraform {
 source = "what_link_to_put_here?"
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[As official docs said](https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/sources#selecting-a-revision):

> By default, Terraform will clone and use the default branch (referenced by HEAD) in the selected repository. You can override this using the ref argument. The value of the ref argument can be any reference that would be accepted by the **git checkout** command, such as **branch**, SHA-1 hash (short or full), or tag names. The Git documentation contains a complete list.

So:

```
source = "git::https://example.com/vpc.git?ref=xxx"  //xxx is a branch name.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. As it is a private git repo, can you please specify a way so that I can pass my credentials or Private Access Token inside this link?